# How to use asset bundle as database instead of PlayerPrefs in unity3d

Tags: ios, database, unity-game-engine, storage, assetbundle

I am new in unity3d. I normally use PlayerPrefs to store data like scores, coins etc in my game. I am working on a game in which I need to make dynamic database which can be alter by server side.

Can I use asset bundle for it? Can anyone provide me the step by step implementation of database via asset bundle. How can I store integer , list and arrays into asset bundle ?

Is there any other options except asset bundle to make database.

Even a little help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 2):

AssetBundles are not supposed to be used as databases. From the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html):

> AssetBundles are files which you can export from Unity to contain
>   assets of your choice. These files use a proprietary compressed format
>   and can be loaded on demand by your application. This allows you to
>   stream in content, such as models, textures, audio clips...

So you could create AssetBundles with *Unity Pro* for your game to download from a server; new levels, character customisations, IAP, etc.

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) is more what you like. Many people use it in games. Here is a [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=euqN5dVNNf0) explaining how to use it in Unity.